# Time taken to empty the tank

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The problem is: 
An electric pump takes **3 hrs** to fill a tank, but due to a leak in the tank now it takes **3 and 1/2 hrs** to fill the **tank**. If the **tank is full, how much time(in hrs)** will the leak require to empty that tank?

**A)21

B)20

C)23

D)22**

I faced this question in an aptitude test for an interview. I couldn't find the solution. Hence I require your help.

Comment: Note that all the answers assume that the leak takes away fluid at a constant rate no matter how full the tank is. That doesn't really sound physically plausible. As one extreme, suppose the leak is halfway up the side of the tank. Then it will _never_ empty the tank, because it stops leaking when the tank is half full. And even if the leak is at the bottom, fluid will leak faster the greater the pressure at the leak site is, which still depends on how full the tank is.

Answer (score 2):

**Some definitions**

- The volume of the tank - $V$
- The time to fill the tank if there were no leak - $T_0$
- The time to fill the tank with the leak $T_l$

We know then that the rate at which the pump can fill the tank is $R_0 = V/T_0$. Assuming the leak leaks at a constant rate $R_l$ then the rate with which the tank is actually filled is $R_0 - R_l$.

The time to fill volume $V$ at this modified rate is just $T_l = V/(R_0-R_l)$. Substituting in $R_0$ and rearranging gives:

$$\frac{T_l}{T_l/T_0-1} = \frac{V}{R_l}$$

Once the tank is full we assume the leak still just removes water at constant rate $R_l$ thus the time to empty the tank is just $V/R_l$ which we have shown is $\frac{T_l}{T_l/T_0-1}$, i.e. $3.5/(3.5/3 - 1) = 21$.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the answer is 21 (but I'm not a fully math person):

- Assume the tank is 15 liter.
- Then the pump fills with speed 15 l/hr / 3 hr = 5 l/hr
- Due to the leak it takes 3,5 hr. Meaning the tank filling is 5 l * 3,5 = 17,5 l.
- The difference is 17,5 l - 15 l = 2,5 l ... during 3,5 hours
- This means 2,5 / 3,5 = 0,714 l/hr to be spoilt.
- The tank filling is 15 l: 15 l / 0,87 = 21 
  So answer A is correct.

Comment: Why would you say the answer is 6 when your calculations end up with 21???

Comment: @Henning Makholm: sorry mistake from my side ... edited.

Answer (score 0):

Let the Volume of the tank be V.

So without leakage the tank is V/3 full in 1 hour.

But with leakage the tank is on V/(3.5) i.e 2V/7 full in 1 hour.

So the leakage contribution is V/3-(2V/7) i.e. 6V/21 - 7V/21  i.e  -V/21.

So the full tank will get emptied in 21 hours when the pump is turned off.

Hence the answer is option (A).

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume that total volume is v and hole rate or empty volume is y hour so as given total time taken to fill is 7/2 hours

V/7/2=V/3-V/y
1/y=1/3-2/7
y=21hours

Answer (score 0):

Input = (1/3) tank per hour

Input - output = (2/7)tank per hour

Output = 1/3 - 2/7 = 1/21 tank per hour,

so takes 21

Regards - Ian H